# Cannot install windows. Compaq Presario CQ62

Tags: windows-7, installation, disc

I bought a used Compaq Presario CQ62 for cheap, and went to install windows on it.  I formatted the partition and went to install when I got this error....

Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing. Make sure all files required for installation are available and restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070017

I have used this disk before with no problems, but internet searching suggested I burn one at 2x speed because that helps for some reason... I'm burning one now, but my question is, why would I get this error, OTHER than the disc being bad?  I'm pretty certain this one isn't as I have used it before...

(ok so the slowly burned cd (using imgburn) didn't work either so it's DEFINITELY not the disc)

Here is what I have tried to do:

- I took one stick of ram out because internet searching also suggested that, but it didn't make a difference.
- I ran memory and hard drive checks and they passed fine.
- I reset the motherboard options to default

What could it be?

Comment: Have you tried using the disc on another machine?  Sorry, but after doing some brief Googling, all answers seem to suggest issues with the disc.

Comment: The problem may not be either (Compact) disc, but your logic/method for ruling that out as the cause is flawed.  Previous use of the old CD does not prove that the CD is still readable today; I've had a CD "go bad".  The slow-burn CD didn't work, yet you claim it is not the cause?  Your "logic" seems to be that since two CDs did not work, therefore the problem cannot be caused by any CD!  You need to demonstrate that one of those CDs is actually readable at the present time.   (Ubuntu Live CDs have a nice feature which can verify the CD from its menu.)

Comment: Slow burn cd's not working with some systems. So you have to try with another fresh cd with high speed and then check it. Also check the old cd's that are they still completely readable because if a sector will be gonna bad from the disk then it won't read and its very important to install the windows.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the disk and copying may simply copy the bad file.  Can you try the original and the copy in another system and see if it works?   As noted by @BryceAtNetwork23, the error is quite specific and points to a CRC error. This from [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-7-installation-error-code-0x80070017/2ea19373-2b4a-47e7-8584-04c6966589c3) is one example and this link has some suggestions like [installing W7 from a USB drive](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)

Also check the BIOS and see which mode the HD uses.  AHCI or IDE  If AHCI, try selecting IDE and try your disk(s) again.

Comment: I think IDE is only for `Vista` & `Win7` while in `AHCI` you can run `Win xp` too. :)

Answer (score 1):

> my question is, why would I get this error, OTHER than the disc being bad?

You could get that issue due to a failing optical drive (the CD drive) or it could be that the ISO you downloaded is corrupt.  Yes, I know you said you installed successfully with this disc before.  Microsoft implies that this error is directly connected to corrupt data [in this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956704).  Yes, I know that the article does not relate to your specific circumstances.

Burning at slower speeds tends to produce discs with less potential data corruption.  That's the reason for that.

It could be the quality of the DVDs that is causing the issue.  It could be that your burner isn't burning as it should.  It could be the cable your burner is connected with.  You could look up instructions for how to install the version of Windows you have, from a flash drive.  You could purchase a copy of Windows instead of using a downloaded copy.  There are multiple options available... but suffice it to say that there are multiple people encountering this issue, and there does not seem to be one simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please make clear what is the OS you are trying to install. Now a day maximum the laptop are supporting only VISTA or Windows 7. If you are trying to install Win Xp you may get error message. Try to install Windows 7. I think it will do.

Comment: The error seems to suggest a disk issue.  New hardware will allow XP to install.  Drivers could be another issue but that does not seem to be the case here based on teh error

Comment: Tag says Windows 7